# $SL (2, K)$ matrix conjugated by $GL(2,K)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can any arbitrary matrix is $SL_2 (K)$, where $K$ is any field be conjugated by some $GL_2 (K)$ element to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & x
\end{pmatrix}?
$$
Apologies in advance if the question is too easy but I thought about it for some time and need it rather quickly.

Comment: What about the identity matrix?

Comment: Good point but let's forget about the identity matrix for the moment! I confess I did not think about that either.

Comment: You will have to give us a precise statement though... Which determinant one matrices are you actually considering?

Comment: The field has a discrete valuation of rank $1$ over it. Does that make things better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u$ be an endomorphism of a two dimensional vector space $V$. Suppose $u$ isn't proportional to the identity. Then there exists a vector $v\in V$ such that $(v,u(v))$ is linearly independent (so that it is a basis of $V$). Then the matrix of $u$ relative to this basis is equal to
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&-\det(u)\\1&\mathrm{tr}(u)
\end{pmatrix}.$$